Docker conteneurized React app doesn't work with keycloak on a server
I'm developing a web application with ReactJS and I use keycloak for authentication.
The application works fine locally, and even when I containerize it with a Dockerfile it still works fine with keycloak. But as soon as I deploy this same docker image on any server and run it, it doesn't work anymore. It's as if my application can't contact keycloak, even though I've checked the client's web origins and valid redirect uri, but I still can't find the source of the problem.
What you see in the image is what's displayed when Keycloak isn't initialized.
Here is the content of my file login.tsx:
import { useKeycloak } from '@react-keycloak/web';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useNavigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

export const Login = () => {
  const { keycloak, initialized } = useKeycloak();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (keycloak?.authenticated) {
      const from = location.state?.from?.pathname || '/';
      navigate(from, { replace: true });
    }
  }, [keycloak, initialized, navigate, location]);

  const handleLogin = () => {
    try {
      console.log('Tentative de connexion à Keycloak...');
      keycloak.login({
        redirectUri: window.location.origin,
        prompt: 'login'
      }).catch(error => {
        console.error('Erreur lors de la connexion:', error);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Erreur lors de l\'initialisation de la connexion:', error);
    }
  };

  if (!initialized) {
    return <div>Initialisation de l'authentification...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div className="login-container">
      <h1>Connexion requise</h1>
      <button onClick={handleLogin} className="login-button">
        Se connecter avec Keycloak
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};  



Here is my Dockerfile:
# Build stage
FROM node:18-alpine AS build

WORKDIR /app

RUN npm install -g pnpm

COPY package.json ./
RUN pnpm install

# Copier le fichier .env d'abord
COPY .env ./
# Charger les variables d'environnement depuis .env (format corrigé)
RUN export $(cat .env | xargs) && \
    echo "VITE_ENV=${VITE_ENV}" > /tmp/env_var

# Copier le reste des fichiers
COPY . .

# Build l'application
RUN pnpm tsc --noEmit
RUN export $(cat .env | xargs) && pnpm build

# Nginx stage
FROM nginx:alpine

# Copier les fichiers buildés
COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=build /tmp/env_var /tmp/env_var

# Copier le fichier .env
COPY .env /usr/share/nginx/html/.env

# Copier la configuration nginx
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
# COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Script pour afficher les variables d'environnement au démarrage
RUN echo "#!/bin/sh" > /docker-entrypoint.d/00-show-env.sh && \
    echo "echo '=== Environment Configuration ==='" >> /docker-entrypoint.d/00-show-env.sh && \
    echo "echo 'Environment variables:'" >> /docker-entrypoint.d/00-show-env.sh && \
    echo "env | grep -E 'VITE_|PUBLIC_'" >> /docker-entrypoint.d/00-show-env.sh && \
    echo "echo '============================'" >> /docker-entrypoint.d/00-show-env.sh && \
    chmod +x /docker-entrypoint.d/00-show-env.sh

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]


And my nginx.conf file:
server {
    listen       0.0.0.0:8000;
    listen  [::]:8000;
    listen       127.0.0.1:8000;
    server_name  92.113.31.2 localhost;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;

    # Configuration CSP unifiée
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "
        default-src 'self';
        connect-src 'self' http://92.113.31.2:8080 http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        frame-src 'self';
        frame-ancestors 'self' http://92.113.31.2:8080 http://92.113.31.2:8000;
        script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';
        style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
        img-src 'self' data: https:;
        object-src 'none';
    " always;

    # CORS headers unifiés
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $http_origin always;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, PATCH" always;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Authorization, Content-Type, Accept" always;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        
        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $http_origin always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, PATCH' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization, Content-Type, Accept' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
            return 204;
        }
    }

    # Proxy pour Keycloak optimisé
    location /realms/todou_companies/ {
        proxy_pass http://92.113.31.2:8080/realms/todou_companies/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        
        proxy_buffer_size 128k;
        proxy_buffers 4 256k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}

I'd like to point out once again that when I run the image locally on my PC it works fine, but the same image doesn't work very well on the servers.
I really hope that ya'll will help me to find a solution.
Thanks in advance.
